# Информация не заноситься в базу MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular2, express

Вообщем есть база на mLab, есть схема:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "599f1a56734d1d4824c6995e"
    },
    "goal": "Buy a car"
}
```

Есть код который заносит инфу в базу, метод post

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Goal = require('../models/goals');

const db = 'mongodb://*********:******@******.mlab.com:57233/smart';
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; 
mongoose.connect(db, function(err){
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error!'+err);
    }
});

router.get('/goals', function(req, res){
    console.log('Get request');
    Goal.find({})
    .exec(function(err, goals){
        if (err){
            console.log('Error retrieving goals');
        }else {
            res.json(goals);
        }
    });
});

router.post('/goal', function(req, res){
    console.log('Post a goal');
    var newGoal = new Goal();
    newGoal.goal = req.body.goal;
    newGoal.save(function(err, insertedGoal){
        if (err){
            console.log('Error saving goal');
        }else {
            res.json(insertedGoal);
        }
    });
});

router.delete('/goals/:goal_id', function(req, res){
    console.log('delete goal');
    Goal.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.goal_id, function(err, deletedGoal){
        if (err) {
            res.send('Error deleting goal');
        }else{
            res.json(deletedGoal)
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

и ещё Goals.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const goalsSchema = new Schema({
    goal: String

},{ versionKey: 'goal' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('goal', goalsSchema, "goals");
```

Связь с базой есть, вроде все работает, но вот проблема в том что любой текст вводимый с input распознаеться как 0. вот так:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59be3d3c02347272e49feb72"
    },
    "goal": 0
}
```

В чем проблема и как что сделать, что бы в "goal" записывался текст который я ввожу в input?

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post('/goal', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.goal);
});
```

А что выводит данный код? Если ничего или 0, то подключите body_parser.
Если всё выводится, то поменяйте ваш скопированный с плохого места запрос:

```
    var newGoal = new Goal();
    newGoal.goal = req.body.goal;
    newGoal.save(function(err, insertedGoal){
        if (err){
            console.log('Error saving goal');
        }else {
            res.json(insertedGoal);
        }
    });
```

На:

```
    var newGoal= new Goal({ goal: req.body.goal});
    newGoal.save(function(err, insertedGoal){
         if (err){
            console.log('Error saving goal');
          } else {
                    res.json(insertedGoal);
          }
     });
```

Comment: Первый код ни делает ничего. подключил bodyParser, никаких изменений

Comment: @Forg не видит ничего как раз таки из-за того, что body-parser не работает и нода не видит что вы ей передаёте.
Вы правильно подключили? В вашей точке входа в приложение нужно прописать:
`var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

Comment: Подключил точно так же как написали вы. Отправляется все тот же 0

Comment: @Forg Надеюсь перед тем как его подключить, вы не забыли его установить?

Comment: конечно не забыл. Только что решил проблему, проблема была в Goals.js, { versionKey: 'goal' }); вот здесь, когда убрал все заработало. Но все равно. спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Goal = require('../models/goals');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const db = 'mongodb://***********ds157233.mlab.com:57233/smart';
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; 
mongoose.connect(db, function(err){
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error!'+err);
    }
});

var app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

router.get('/goals', function(req, res){
    console.log('Get request');
    Goal.find({})
    .exec(function(err, goals){
        if (err){
            console.log('Error retrieving goals');
        }else {
            res.json(goals);
        }
    });
});

router.post('/goal', function(req, res){
    console.log('Post a goal');
    var newGoal= new Goal({ goal: req.body.goal});
    newGoal.save(function(err, insertedGoal){
         if (err){
            console.log('Error saving goal');
          } else {
             res.send(insertedGoal);
          }
     });
});

router.delete('/goals/:goal_id', function(req, res){
    console.log('delete goal');
    Goal.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.goal_id, function(err, deletedGoal){
        if (err) {
            res.send('Error deleting goal');
        }else{
            res.json(deletedGoal)
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Вот код с подключеным bodyParserои